# How to reduce this series to a single equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Somehow, my textbook was about to reduce this series to a single equation:

[image]

I know that you can use the equation $$S=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

for the sum of the first n integers but I don't think this applies here

Comment: You can prove it by induction, if you know how that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telescope:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac n{2n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :**

Rewrite
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right),
$$
and then you will have a [a telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) where after cancellation you will only have the first term and the last term. I hope this helps.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by induction on $n$ that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$

If $n=1$ it's easly true: $\sum_{k=1}^{1}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{1}{(2-1)(2+1)}=\frac{1}{1\cdot3}$ that is equal to $\frac{n}{2n+1}$ when $n=1$.

Suppose now the formula valid for $n-1$ (this is called inductive hypotesis) and let's prove it for $n$.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=(*)$.

Now you can apply the inductive hypotesis to RHS, to write the first term (that is the sum of the first $n-1$ terms) as $\frac{n-1}{2(n-1)+1}$ that is equal to $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$. Hence you have

$(*)=
\frac{n-1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{(2n+1)(n-1)+1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{n(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{n}{(2n+1)}$ as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logical way to think let the sum extend only upto two terms so the sum would be 1/3+1/15 = 6/15 = 2/5 so now in terms of n since you know you have taken only two terms you can write it as n/(2*n + 1) you can cross check by taking one more term for n= 3.